# Autodesk Forge register job conflict

Tags: autodesk, autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

When `POST`ing to `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/register` I sometiems receive the following error:

```
{
   Diagnostic: The request is rejected as it conflicts with a previous request that is in-progress., 
   registerKeys: {}, 
   Result: Conflict
}
```

How can I find out which job is already in progress so that I can track its progress and get its result?

Comment: Hi, I do not think there is an API that tells the status of all translating progress. The only API is to check the status of the specific job such as
***v1***:  /viewingservice/v1/:urn
***v2***:  /modelderivative/v2/designdata/:urn/manifest
So, the suggestion I can have is to check the status firstly of the specific job before you request a new translating.

Answer (score 0):

First, this is the old API, you need to consider using the ModelDerivtive API instead (ie https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2)

Like Xiaodond said there is no API to collect all jobs currently processing on your account. You need to request each URN manifest to determine how many jobs runs on this model as know you can translate to SVF, but also export to other formats such as obj, stl, ... when it is possible. Manifest end point and documentation here - https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET/

Last, we are working on a webhook solution which will be a better solution as a Webhook will call you back when a job is starting and completes. Webhooks aren't yet available at the time of this post, but you should be notified via the developer newsletter when it will be on production.

Hope that helps,